# Is there any performance gain if I put SQL server DB files on a separate EBS volume?

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis-7, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running IIS7 + 2008 R2 SQL database on an EBS volume and wondering if there will be a performance gain by atatching a separate EBS volume just for the database files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "performance game" if you separate database files that might be in contention.  For example, if you have two local disks, it might be beneficial to put your .ldf logs on one disk, and your database files on the other disk.

Q: Do you really believe your databases might be in contention with each other "in the cloud"?

If so, by all means try separating them.  But I'm guessing it's pretty unlikely...